# Python TypeError: CommandEvent.GetString(): too many arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am currently making a UI in python using wx. I am trying to have multiple tabs active at the same time, but at the same time I am trying to keep either a list or int value active and showing in the bottom right corner on any tab at all times. Unfortunately I seem to have run into a road block. When I run the code below I get the error:

i = parent.GetString(Points.a)
TypeError: CommandEvent.GetString(): too many arguments

Honestly I am only a year into coding practice and I don't really know what this error means. If possible, could someone please explain it to me and possible give me some tips on how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

```css
import wx
class Points:
    c = 14
    a = [14]
    b = "{}\n" .format(a)

class MOC(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.poi = wx.StaticText(self, label=Points.b, pos=(400, 400))
        select = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, '+1', size=(90, 30))
        select.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add)

    def add(self, parent):
        i = parent.GetString(Points.a)
        Points.a.remove(Points.c)
        Points.c += 1
        Points.a.append(Points.c)
        self.poi.SetLabel(i)
        
class TOS(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        wx.StaticText(self, label=Points.b, pos=(400, 400))

class UIFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size = (500,500), title = "Mind")
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        page1 = MOC(nb)
        page2 = TOS(nb)
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Means")
        nb.AddPage(page2, "Types")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    UIFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `i = parent.GetString(Points.a)` you are passing the argument Points.a but `GetString` has no arguments because it is used to get the string from an item i.e. `self.Item.GetString()`.
`Points.a` is not a wx defined item, it is in fact a python `list`, to access that you should change the offending line above with
`i = str(Points.a[0])` or
`i = Points.a[0]` or
`i = Points.a` or
`i = str(Points.a)` depending on your requirements.

Depending on which access method you choose, you may have to alter the
`self.poi.SetLabel(i)` as well, as `i` could be a `list` or an `int` rather than the required `str`

Running with the first option works without further changes